# How does availability improve with less maintenance hours?

Tags: regression, correlation

I'm trying to determine a relationship that shows how the availability (Ao) of equipment improves with maintenance hours.  For example, our current equipment is alloted 30 maintenance hours to keep it running because it's old and needs replacing.  For this we get an availability of 50%.  A company tells us that their equipment will only requires 5 maintenance hours.  My question is how could I show an increase in availability with reduced hours?  I would like to show how the availability changes with maintenance hours in increments of 5 hours (Ac).

I thought about a simple relation ship like (1-Ac*Ao/30), but that just reduces to 1-Ao if Ac=30, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  If I assume a linear relationship where Ao is a perfect 100% at zero maintenance hours I can develop a simple realtionship.